# How to integrate by parts the vectorial product between a vector and a gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

I am having a problem trying to check if the identity below should be positive or negative.

$$ \int\;  \boldsymbol{A} \times (\boldsymbol{\nabla} a ) = \pm \int (\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{A} )a$$

where $a$ is a scalar function and the vectors are defined in 2-dimensional space.

For me the correct development should be:

First change the order of the vectorial product:
$$ =- \int (\boldsymbol{\nabla} a )\times  \boldsymbol{A} $$
than integrating by parts and eliminating the surface term:

$$= + \int a (\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{A} ) $$
therefore the identity is positive. But I am not sure if this is correct. I try using index notation to prove, but got confused:
$$ \int A_i \epsilon_{ij}(\nabla_j a )= -\int (\nabla_jA_i \epsilon_{ij}) a = \int (\nabla_jA_i \epsilon_{ji}) a$$
again positive.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. It looks like you're working with $2$-dimensional vectors, which you didn't state explicitly.

Comment: Adding a constant to $a$ changes the right side but not the left?

Comment: yes I am in two dimensions. I edited. Thanks

Comment: Leaving out the boundary term, for starters, just makes this incorrect, unless you say explicitly that either $\mathbf A$ or $a$ has compact support. You refer to "eliminating the surface term" — this is referring to the boundary term as if you were in 3 dimensions. Very confusing. At any rate, the usual Stokes's/Green's Theorem gives $\int_{\partial R} a\vec A\cdot d\vec r = \iint_R (\nabla\times(a\vec A) = \iint_R \big(\nabla a\times\vec A + a(\nabla\times\vec A)\big)$.

Comment: Also, please do not use irrelevant tags. This is just multivariable/vector calculus. If you want a tensor-analysis symbolic proof, that's still not differential geometry. :)

Comment: Okay. I see the problem. Thanks for the answer